# Solving system of PDEs with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve a system of coupled PDEs with zero-flux boundary conditions on a large domain.
I have two problems: 
1) Is there a possibility to use results of NDSolve as inititial conditions? As the results are given by an interpolating function, I guess this could be difficult. However, my RAM is not sufficient for long evaluations and evaluation using {t,0,10} and then {t,10,20} (for instance) does not seem to match.

2) If I use my initial conditions (see following code), I think the evaluation is wrong. A stationary bump in z emerges. I think the reason for this is the error 
NDSolve::mxsst: Using maximum number of grid points 100 allowed by the MaxPoints or MinStepSize options for independent variable x.
How can I solve the system anyway?

The code:

```
(* Parameters *)
eps = 1.4434; m = 0.3; c11 = 0.1732;
(* PDEs *)
pde1 := D[pp[t, x, y], t] == 0.05*Laplacian[pp[t, x, y], {x, y}] + pp[t, x, y]*(1 - c11*pp[t, x, y] - z[t, x, y]/(1 + pp[t, x, y]^2));
pde2 := D[z[t, x, y], t] == 0.05*Laplacian[z[t, x, y], {x, y}] + z[t, x, y]*(eps*pp[t, x, y]/(1 + pp[t, x, y]^2) - m);
(* Initial conditions *)
ic1[x_, y_] := Which[Sqrt[(x - 50)^2 + (y - 50)^2] < 1, 6, True, 0];
ic2[x_, y_] := 
Which[Sqrt[(x - 50)^2 + (y - 50)^2] < 1, 0.5, True, 1/c11];
(* Numerical approximation using NDSolve with zero-flux boundary conditions*)
soln2d = NDSolve[{pde1, pde2, 
 (D[pp[t, x, y], x] /. x -> 0) == 0, 
 (D[pp[t, x, y], y] /. y -> 0) == 0, 
 (D[z[t, x, y], x] /. x -> 0) == 0, 
 (D[z[t, x, y], y] /. y -> 0) == 0, 
 (D[pp[t, x, y], x] /. x -> 100) == 0, 
 (D[pp[t, x, y], y] /. y -> 100) == 0, 
 (D[z[t, x, y], x] /. x -> 100) == 0, 
 (D[z[t, x, y], y] /. y -> 100) == 0, 
 z[0, x, y] == ic1[x, y], 
 pp[0, x, y] == ic2[x, y]}, 
 {pp, z}, {t, 0, 500}, {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100}];
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: 1. " As the results are given by an interpolating function, I guess this could be difficult." No, there'll be no difficulty. The usage of `InterpolatingFunction` is just the same as analytic functions like `Sin`, `Exp`, etc. in this case. If you fails to, please show a specific example. 2. For unsmooth i.c. `NDSolve` will automatically choose too dense a grid, you need to manually control the spatial grid in this case using e.g. `Method-> {"MethodOfLines", 
 "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", "MaxPoints" -> 100, "MinPoints" -> 100, "DifferenceOrder" -> 4}}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your description on how to check the solution was a bit vague, so I did not do it. Try this, though:

```
(*Parameters*)
eps = 1.4434; m = 0.3; c11 = 0.1732;
(*PDEs*)
pde1 := 
  D[pp[t, x, y], t] == 
   0.05*Laplacian[pp[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
    pp[t, x, y]*(1 - c11*pp[t, x, y] - z[t, x, y]/(1 + pp[t, x, y]^2));
pde2 := D[z[t, x, y], t] == 
   0.05*Laplacian[z[t, x, y], {x, y}] + 
    z[t, x, y]*(eps*pp[t, x, y]/(1 + pp[t, x, y]^2) - m);
(*Initial conditions*)

ic1[x_, y_] := Which[Sqrt[(x - 50)^2 + (y - 50)^2] < 1, 6, True, 0];
ic2[x_, y_] := 
  Which[Sqrt[(x - 50)^2 + (y - 50)^2] < 1, 0.5, True, 1/c11];
(*Numerical approximation using NDSolve with zero-flux boundary \
conditions*)
soln2d = 
 Monitor[NDSolveValue[{pde1, pde2, z[0, x, y] == ic1[x, y], 
    pp[0, x, y] == ic2[x, y]}, {pp, z}, {t, 0, 
    500}, {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[{0, 0}, {100, 100}], 
   EvaluationMonitor :> (monitor = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])]
  , monitor]
```

This uses the finite element method to solve the PDEs.

To your firs question: Yes you can use an `InterpolatingFunction` as an initial condition, just like any other function. Being able to do so is a strong point of Mathematica.

Comment: 1: OK, then I'll try this. Is there also the possibility to store this in a file and load it later as initial condition? I ask as Mathematica sometimes crashes.
2: Does the "\[Element] Rectangle[..]" contain zero flux bc? I copied this code and I get the following error messages:
CoefficientArrays::poly: pp$2407-0.05 (pp$2408+pp$2409)-pp (1-0.1732 pp-z/(1+pp^2)) is not a polynomial.
NDSolveValue::femper: PDE parsing error of {pp$3017-0.05 (pp$3018+pp$3019)-pp (1-0.1732 pp-z/(1+pp^2)),-(-0.3+(1.4434 pp)/(1+pp^2)) z+z$3017-0.05 (z$3020+z$3021)}. Inconsistent equation dimensions.

Comment: @gumpel, you can store an interpolating function just like any other expression.

Comment: OK, thanks.
Any idea regarding the second problem?

Comment: Or does the code you have given work for you?

Comment: @gumpel, the code runs without errors. If it does not for you: what version do you have? what issues does it show?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have version 11.3. It shows the following errors:
`CoefficientArrays::poly: pp$3209-0.05 (pp$3210+pp$3211)-pp (1-0.1732 pp-z/(1+pp^2)) is not a polynomial. `
and 
`NDSolveValue::femper: PDE parsing error of {pp$3209-0.05 (pp$3210+pp$3211)-pp (1-0.1732 pp-z/(1+pp^2)),-(-0.3+(1.4434 pp)/(1+pp^2)) z+z$3209-0.05 (z$3212+z$3213)}. Inconsistent equation dimensions.`

Comment: @gumpel, nonlinear finite elements got added in version 12.0

Comment: OK, thank you. Do you have a suggestion for an alternative?

Comment: @gumpel, may a search for `NDSolve::mxsst` can help, I think there ample examples for this message on this site.

Comment: OK, I chose to upgrade to version 12 :) so your code works now. However, could you also help me with plotting this? In 11.3, it was just Plot3D[Evaluate[{z[200, x, y]} /. soln2d], {x, 5, 10}, {y, 5, 10}, but this does not work here.

Comment: @gumpel have a look at the ref page for `NDSolveValue` there are plenty examples. Or replace `NDSolveValue` with `NDSolve` and use what you have now; I find the NDSolveValue-form the result is returned in more convenient.